# Link menu nav to two divs with the same ID in two different tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a single web page with a menu nav that jumps into every div in a single page. I then created a tab to split sections with the same categories but different content. Now the menu nav only works with the first tab and not on the second tab. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```html
 <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#demo">Demo video</a></li>
    </ul>
    
     <div class="myTab">
        <ul class="nav-tab">
      <li data-target="myTab" class="active">product1</li>
      <li data-target="myTab">product2</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="inner-tab">
      <div class="item active">
       <div class="features">
        <p>features of p1</p>
       </div>
       <div class="about">
        <p>about of p1</p>
       </div>
       <div class="demo">
        <p>demo of p1</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="features">
        <p>features of p2</p>
       </div>
       <div class="about">
        <p>about of p2</p>
       </div>
       <div class="demo">
        <p>demo of p2</p>
       </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using ids?  id is meant to be unique.  Why wouldn't you use classes or attributes (like name=".....")?

Comment: You mean I can use classes for link? Sorry I do not know that classes can be use as link.

Comment: Look at this, this will hellp you with your id's and class's problem. [The Difference Between ID and Class](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the solution I need, The problem is how can I jump from nav menu to the specific div I want. Any jquery or javascript to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is to give each element a unique ID and reference that ID from an anchor tag in the menu. You cannot reference a class applied to multiple elements, it must be a unique ID. I provided an example in the code snippet.

You can use javascript to scroll to an element which tends to provide a nicer experience. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

```css
#nav {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#nav ul {
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#nav ul a {
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"Helvetica"
}

#nav ul li {
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#nav ul li.current-menu-item {
 background:#ddd
}

#nav ul li:hover {
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#nav ul ul {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#nav ul ul li {
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#nav ul ul a {
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#nav ul ul ul {
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:block
}

div {
  margin: 200px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Features</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#p1-features">Product 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#p2-features">Product 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    
  <li><a href="#">Details</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#p1-about">Product 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#p2-about">Product 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    
  <li><a href="#">Demo Video</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#p1-demo">Product 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#p2-demo">Product 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</nav>

<div class="item active">
  <div id='p1-features' class="features">
    <p>features of p1</p>
   </div>
  <div id='p1-about' class="about">
    <p>about of p1</p>
  </div>
  <div id='p1-demo' class="demo">
    <p>demo of p1</p>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="item">
  <div id='p2-features' class="features">
    <p>features of p2</p>
  </div>
  <div id='p2-about' class="about">
    <p>about of p2</p>
  </div>
  <div id='p2-demo'class="demo">
    <p>demo of p2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed double quotes before your 'feature' id.
Also you shouldn't use ids, but classes for your links!

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I just edited my code, now how can I link the navigation to work with classes?

Comment: With jQuery, you can use scrollTop in a function like this:                                                      function linkTo(class){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(class).position().top}, 'slow');
 }